# Using Integrals With Internal Rate of Return?

Tags: integration

I'm taking a Calculus 2 course this Fall, and for my honors project, I will be using the Internal Rate of Return (IRR) function. My professor is requesting that I figure out a way to use an integral with the IRR.

The cash flow scenario being modeled has first period/outgoing/negative cash flow (NPV variable), and one final terminal positive cash flow (CFx), with each period between the first period and final period being 0.

I've taken the NPV function: $NPV=\sum _{n=0}^N\:\frac{CFx}{\left(1+IRR\right)^x}$ , and as we just have one positive terminal cash flow, I've removed the summation and solved for the IRR (with the terminal year=x), with the function becoming $IRR=\left(\frac{CFx}{NPV}\right)^{\frac{1}{x}}-1$

As the IRR function is not cumulative, taking an integral of the IRR function as defined would be meaningless.

Does anyone have an idea as to how an integral could be used for the project?

I really appreciate any assistance that's provided.

Comment: I suggest that you edit the tags, and try to find ones fitting for the terminology you are expecting the reader to understand. That way, you will attract the attention of those who are actually familiar with that terminology and can follow your post and offer useful responses.

Answer (score 1):

Although, in the real world, treating cash flows as a continuous function of time is extremely unrealistic, theoretically you can do it.

To get an integral, it helps to think in dimensions.

NPV should have dimensions of money, lets say USD, so $[NPV]=[USD]$. Cash flow as the name says, its a flow, so the dimension should be [CF]=[USD/time]. And the interest rate or the IRR are measured in $time^{-1}$ or $[r]=[\frac{1}{time}] $.

So, in order to get a dimensionally homogenuous equation for NPV, start writing it´s formula as following:

$$NPV(t_{0})=\sum_{k=1}^{nm}\frac{CF(t_{0}+k \frac{\Delta t}{m})}{\left(1+r(t_{0}+k\frac{\Delta t}{m}) \frac{\Delta t}{m}\right)^{k}} \frac{\Delta t}{m}$$

In general, we assume $\frac{\Delta t}{m} = 1$, and you get back the formula you wrote above, but here we want to take $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} $.

Rewrite the factor in the denominator as

$$\left(1+r(t_{0}+k\frac{\Delta t}{m}) \frac{\Delta t}{m}\right)^{k}=e^{k{\log\left(1+r(t_{0}+k\frac{\Delta t}{m}) \frac{\Delta t}{m}\right)}}$$

so the NVP formula becomes

$$NPV(t_{0})=\sum_{k=1}^{nm}CF(t_{0}+k \frac{\Delta t}{m})e^{-k{\log\left(1+r(t_{0}+k\frac{\Delta t}{m}) \frac{\Delta t}{m}\right)}}\frac{\Delta t}{m}$$

Call $t_{n}=t_{0}+n\Delta t$ and take the limit $\lim_{m \rightarrow \infty} $ to arrive at

$$NPV(t_{0})=\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{n}}CF(t)e^{-R(t)(t_{n}-t_{0})}dt$$

The IRR is the $R(t)$ that satisfies

$$NPV(t_{0})-\int_{t_{0}}^{t_{n}}CF(t)e^{-R(t)(t_{n}-t_{0})}dt =0$$

Note that in this formula it is not easy to isolate R, you would have to resort in numerical methods to do so. Hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! I was not expecting such a detailed response! Give me a day or two to look this over. Thank you!

Comment: A couple of questions for you. 1) Δ/m can you explain what this represents? 2) I assume "k" is time or years? Thanks!

Comment: to make the equation dimensionally homogeneous you have to multiply by $\Delta t$. The left hand side has units USD, so should be the right hand side. Cash flow has units USD/time, so you multiply by $\Delta t$ to end up with only USD. Also, later when you take the limit to continuous time, it will become $dt$.